# Beamer \pause grey

Tags: beamer, pause

I want to pause items in beamer, and have all items in grey except the non-paused one. [This question is similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112598/beamer-grey-out-items-after-pause), but does not work for me. MWE below

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercovered{%
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Important frame}

\begin{block}<1>{Important thing I}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<2>{Important thing II}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<3>{Important thing III}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<4>{Important thing IV}
blabla
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the closest I get, with the difference that \paused elements are only greyed after they have been introduced. I would like them to be visibly grey even before they were introduced

[image]

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `still covered` option.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Leandriis, adding `still covered` in `\setbeamercovered` does the trick. Here the updated MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercovered{%
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}},  
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Important frame}

\begin{block}<1>{Important thing I}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<2>{Important thing II}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<3>{Important thing III}
blabla
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}<4>{Important thing IV}
blabla
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```