# greying things out in beamer after they are shown

Tags: beamer

I looked around, and it seems like I didn't find quite what I wanted, this is the closest: [Beamer \pause grey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600587/beamer-pause-grey)

What I want is to (possibly using setbeamcovered) have a few slides (so I need to restore this after those slides) so that \pause doesn't show the next item until it is shown, but when the item is shown, it greys out *everything before it*.

Is that possible using setbeamcovered?

This also helps:

[Beamer grey out items after pause](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112598/beamer-grey-out-items-after-pause)

with \only - but it completely makes the item disappear rather than grey out.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[sansserif,mathserif]{beamer}


\setbeamercovered{%
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}},
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{slide title}

\only<1> {
I should appear only in the beginning, and then grey myself out. But for some reason I disappear after a click!
}

\pause

\only<2> {
I should appear only in the middle, and then grey myself out. I don't show at all before the click. I also disappear - not good.
}

\pause

\only<3> {
I don't appear until second click, and everything above me is greyed out
}



\end{frame}

%% any changes should be restored here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired effect by using `\uncover` instead of `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamercovered{%
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}},
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{slide title}

\uncover<1> {
I should appear only in the beginning, and then grey myself out. But for some reason I disappear after a click!
}

\pause


\uncover<2> {
I should appear only in the middle, and then grey myself out. I don't show at all before the click. I also disappear - not good.
}

\pause

\uncover<3> {
I don't appear until second click, and everything above me is greyed out
}



\end{frame}

%% any changes should be restored here

\end{document}
```

[image]